# Remove lines from index.html after building with Ant task and regex

Tags: ant, build, build-process, sencha-cmd

I'm building an ExtJS application with Sencha Cmd and would like to remove some lines from the index.html file after it has been built.

I know that this can basically be done by placing Ant tasks inside the build.xml file. Those tasks can look something like this:

```
<target name="-after-build">
    <replace file="index.html" token="some text" value="some new text"/>
</target>
```

Now I don't want to just replace some text but want to remove some complete lines that are recognized by regex. I also managed to replace multiple lines by regex with the replaceregexp task but don't now how to completely remove them. I only managed to replace them with a blank.

The lines I'd like to remove from my index.html file look something like this:

```
//<dev>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dev-files.js"></script>
...
//</dev>
```

Thanks & best regards